# Python2.7 with OpenCV 3.3.0 - VideoCapture problem

Tags: python, python-2.7, opencv

Estou rodando OpenCV 3.3.0. com Python 2.7 em uma máquina Windows 7 Professional x64, e quando executo o código abaixo, cai nos prints "Algo deu errado" e "Finalizado ..."

```
import cv2

capture = cv2.VideoCapture("video.mp4") #The video is in the same folder

if(not capture.isOpened()):
    print "Something went wrong"

while(cap.isOpened()):
     ret, frame = cap.read()

     cv2.imshow('Frame', frame)

print "Finished ..."

capture.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Dei uma pesquisada, e indicaram que eu deveria copiar o arquivo "opencv_ffmpeg{VersaoDoOpenCvSemPontos}.dll" para a pasta raiz do Python, e assim eu fiz.

Eu copiei o arquivo "opencv_ffmpeg330_64.dll" (e também copiei renomeado como "opencv_ffmpeg330.dll") para:

- A pasta raiz do Python
- A pasta DLLs do Python
- A pasta Lib do Python
- A pasta Lib/site-packages do Python

Mas nada disso funcionou ...

Continuei pesquisando, e um tópico sugeriu que fosse problemas de codec, então eu baixei o FFMPEG, adicionei ele à minha variàvel de ambiente PATH, converti meu "video.mp4" para "video.avi" com o ffmpeg, mas nada de funcionar.

Então eu baixei o VLC media player, pra garantir que tenho os codecs instalados, mas continua dando que o video não abre. (O vídeo executa nos meus players, tanto em mp4 quanto avi, sem nenhum problema)

Eu não estou encontrando solução para isso, alguém já enfrentou esse tipo de problema e sabe como resolver?

Comment: Poderia traduzir sua pergunta?

Comment: Feito!  Quando fui postar, estava na versão em inglês, nem me toquei que tinha sido redirecionado para o pt-br ... falha minha!

Comment: Os únicos problemas aparentes do seu código são: (1) você usa duas variáveis diferentes (`capture` e `cap`) e (2) você não usa o `cv2.waitKey(1)`, por exemplo, para aguardar algum tempo após a exibição de cada quadro do vídeo. Sobre ele estar imprimindo erro como se houvesse falha no vídeo, eu realmente não consegui reproduzir. Se você instalou o OpenCV com o pip, não deveria ser mesmo necessário copiar qualquer DLL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolvi fazendo um downgrade do OpenCV para o OpenCV 3.0.0.

Copiei o cv.pyd para a pasta Lib/site-packages do Python, e o arquivo opencv_ffmpeg300.dll para a pasta raiz do Python, e funcionou!